# Book about a girl with spirit-like powers who is being chased by dark shadow spirits

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book like 5 or more years ago about this girl and she had some kind of powers that had something to do with spirits and an Ouija Board. The cover was of the girl and said board. It had this scene appear at the end where some like dark shadow like spirit was chasing her down a subway type area and she like kills it with her power. She's like being chased by these spirits and the same thing happened to her mom I think?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Great first question! Do you have any more details, such as where and when it was read or published? While we have you, please do check out the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: Moonstar? Paging a young Miss [Dani Moonstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danielle_Moonstar)?